# Why do I get a NotFoundError when trying to save my model with: model.save('my_model', save_format='tf')

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am using the Tensorflow Keras Subclassing API to Build Dynamic Models, but when I try to save my model I get a NotFoundError.

```
class WideAndDeepModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, units=30, activation="relu", **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)  # needed to support naming the model
        self.norm_layer_wide = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
        self.norm_layer_deep = tf.keras.layers.Normalization()
        self.hidden1 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.hidden2 = tf.keras.layers.Dense(units, activation=activation)
        self.main_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        self.aux_output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
        
    def call(self, inputs):
        input_wide, input_deep = inputs
        norm_wide = self.norm_layer_wide(input_wide)
        norm_deep = self.norm_layer_deep(input_deep)
        hidden1 = self.hidden1(norm_deep)
        hidden2 = self.hidden2(hidden1)
        concat = tf.keras.layers.concatenate([norm_wide, hidden2])
        output = self.main_output(concat)
        aux_output = self.aux_output(hidden2)
        return output, aux_output

tf.random.set_seed(42)  # extra code – just for reproducibility
model = WideAndDeepModel(30, activation="relu", name="my_cool_model")

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-3)
model.compile(loss="mse", loss_weights=[0.9, 0.1], optimizer=optimizer,
              metrics=["RootMeanSquaredError"])
model.norm_layer_wide.adapt(X_train_wide)
model.norm_layer_deep.adapt(X_train_deep)
history = model.fit(
    (X_train_wide, X_train_deep), (y_train, y_train), epochs=10,
    validation_data=((X_valid_wide, X_valid_deep), (y_valid, y_valid)))
eval_results = model.evaluate((X_test_wide, X_test_deep), (y_test, y_test))
weighted_sum_of_losses, main_loss, aux_loss, main_rmse, aux_rmse = eval_results
y_pred_main, y_pred_aux = model.predict((X_new_wide, X_new_deep))
```

but when I try to save my model, using:

```
model.save('my_model', save_format='tf')
```

I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NotFoundError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[94], line 1
----> 1 model.save('my_model', save_format='tf')

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py:70, in filter_traceback.<locals>.error_handler(*args, **kwargs)
     67     filtered_tb = _process_traceback_frames(e.__traceback__)
     68     # To get the full stack trace, call:
     69     # `tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering()`
---> 70     raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
     71 finally:
     72     del filtered_tb

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py:53, in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     51 try:
     52   ctx.ensure_initialized()
---> 53   tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
     54                                       inputs, attrs, num_outputs)
     55 except core._NotOkStatusException as e:
     56   if name is not None:

NotFoundError: {{function_node __wrapped__SaveV2_dtypes_43_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} Failed to rename: my_model\variables\variables_temp/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001.tempstate16756848698604293682 to: my_model\variables\variables_temp/part-00000-of-00001.data-00000-of-00001 : The system cannot find the path specified.
; No such process [Op:SaveV2]
```